# Complex number-argands diagram

Tags: complex-numbers

The complex numbers, $z$ and $w$ satisfy the inequalities $|z-3-2i|\le2$ and $|w-7-5i|\le 1$. 
Find the least possible value of $|z-w|$.
Thats my work till now

$$|z-3-2i| = |z-(3+2i)| |z|-|3+2i| |z|-|3+2i| \le 2 |z|^2-|3+2i|^2 \le 2^2 z\overline{z}-(13)\le 4 |z|^2 < 17$$

Comment: Do you know geometric interpretation of complex numbers? Draw circles $|z-z_1| \le 2$ and $|z-z_2| \le 1$ for $z_1 = 3 + 2i$, $z_2 = 7 + 5i$, then connect their centres with a line segment. It should be easier to understand problem now ;) Just find distance between $z_1$ and $z_2$, then subtract sum of circle radiuses.

Comment: I only know ways of representing complex numbers till now through vectors and argand diagrams by plotting just their coordinates. where do that circle come from?

Comment: @Kusavil, you could write up your comment as an answer. com nets may disappear for no reason.

Answer (score 4):

The figure is the Argand diagram that represents the problem.
[image]

Inside the circle centered at $C_1$ are the numbers $z$ such that $|z-3-2i|\le2$, inside the other circle the points such that $|w-7-5i|\le 1$
The searched points are the red points and, since the triangle $C_1,C_2,M$ has sides that form a Pythagorean triple, the hypotenuse has length $5$ and the  red segment has lenght $2$.

Comment: I'm interested in the picture,could you tell me how can I make it?~\(≧▽≦)/~

Comment: Use pakage: http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

We can imagine $z$ and $\omega$ are in the circle $\odot_1$(centre$(3,2)$) and $\odot_2$(centre$(7,5)$),according to 
$|z−3−2i|\leqslant2$ and $|w−7−5i|\leqslant1$,their radius are $2$ and $1$.
So,the question becomes to calculate the shortest distance between two circles.
$$d_{min}=\sqrt{(3-7)^2+(2-5)^2}-1-2=2$$